# What does \$\beta\$ represent with respect to the length of a transmission line?

Tags: rf, impedance, transmission-line, s-parameters

The picture below shows the ABCD parameters for a transmission line of length \$l\$ from [this video](https://youtu.be/rfbvmGwN_8o).

**Question: What does \$\beta\$ represent?**

[image: ABCD Parameters of a transmission line]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beta is the phase constant, the change in phase per unit length.

Comment: Is that the same as \$\frac{1}{\lambda}\$?  If not, how does it relate to wavelength?

Comment: I believe it is 2 Pi over lambda. On my phone at the moment, I can give more detail when I get to my desktop.

Comment: Now that I know what it was called I was able to search and find that it is, indeed you are correct: \$\beta = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\$, \$\lambda=\frac{2\pi}{\beta}\$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant#Definition . Thanks!